# Keeping file path with read.csv

Tags: r

I'm loading a bunch of csv's using:

```
data_path_list <- list.files(path = getwd(), recursive = T, pattern = "\\QVDR.csv", full.names = T)

data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(data_path_list, function(x) {
  read.csv(x, skip = 3)
})) %>% 
  mutate(
    Source = data_path_list
  )
```

I'm using the Source column to try to keep the path that loaded that particular file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

With `purrr` you can have a pretty elegant solution.

`map` works pretty much like `lapply`, but it gives you more flexibility on the output.

In this case with the function `map_dfr` you are applying the same function over the list, and also you are row-binding together all the dataframes at the end.

With `.id` you can keep track of the sources as you requested. Technically it works by assigning to the column `Source` the value of the names of the list. That's why I used `set_names` at the beginning.

```
library(purrr)

data <- data_path_list %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr(read.csv, skip = 3, .id = "Source")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `dplyr` (`mutate`), then I strongly recommend you use `bind_rows` in place of `do.call(rbind, ...)`. One nice benefit is that it can assign an `id` field:

```r
# setup
write.csv(mtcars[1:3,], file="mt.csv")
file.copy("mt.csv", "mt2.csv")

library(dplyr)
rawdat <- sapply(list.files(pattern = "mt.*\\.csv", full.names = TRUE), read.csv, simplify = FALSE)
names(rawdat)
# [1] "./mt.csv"  "./mt2.csv"
bind_rows(rawdat, .id = "id")
#          id             X  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  ./mt.csv     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  ./mt.csv Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3  ./mt.csv    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4 ./mt2.csv     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 5 ./mt2.csv Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 6 ./mt2.csv    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Note: one difference between `sapply(vec, fun, simplify=FALSE)` and `lapply(vec, fun)` is that if `vec` is not named, `sapply` will assign its values as names, effectively `names(vec) <- vec`; `lapply` will not. One can get the same effect with `lapply` with `setNames(lapply(vec, fun), vec)`.